# Group a multidimensional array by a particular value

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I have a multidimensional array and am trying to group them according to the value of array properties.

I'm trying to group them by id, but I won't actually know the id beforehand. So, it's not like I can put it in a for loop and say while i < 7, because I won't know that 7 is the maximum value for the id value,

```
Array (
 [0] => Array (
      [name] => R8900
      [type] => public
      [id] => 1
      )
[1] => Array (
      [name] => R8944
      [type] => public
      [id] => 1
      )
[2] => Array (
      [name] => R8922
      [type] => private
      [id] => 3
      )
[3] => Array (
      [name] => R8816
      [type] => private
      [id] => 3
      )
 [4] => Array (
      [name] => R7434
      [type] => VIP
      [id] => 7
      )
)
```

What I'm hoping to produce:

```
Array (

[1] => Array (
      [0] => Array (
                [name] => R8900
                [type] => public
                )
      [1] => Array (
                [name] => R8944
                [type] => public
                )
      )

 [3] => Array (
      [2] => Array (
             [name] => R8922
             [type] => private
             )

      [3] => Array (
             [name] => R8816
             [type] => private
             )
      )

 [7] => Array (
      [4] => Array (
             [name] => R7434
             [type] => VIP
             )
      )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something as simple as:

```
var result:Object = {};

for each(var i:Object in input)
{
    if(!result.hasOwnProperty(i.id))
    {
        result[i.id] = [];
    }

    result[i.id].push(i);
    delete i.id;
}
```

Comment: How can I trace the "result" property?

Comment: @xyonme Because `result` and its contents are Objects, you need to iterate over the contents to debug it. Alternatively, you could create a custom data type for result and the inner objects with your own `toString()` definitions.

Comment: the delete statement : is it deleting the whole object? why do we delete the object. The result in Array would be best?

Comment: @xyonme I don't delete the whole object... It only deletes the `id` property because in your question your desired output did not contain it.

Comment: Ah yes yes. what about the array result?  would u show me how to do the result as an Array , not as an Object?

Comment: @xyonme Because you don't have consecutive keys, an Array would not be very suitable for this task.

Comment: with this method, How do I  trace how many result was made?  `trace ("result length",result[1].id, result[3].id);` I got undefined. I need to use the index of the object thats made and the properties @Marty Thanks

Comment: @xyonme Based on the output you wanted, you need to access those objects via `result[3][0].name`, that being the first item in the array holding all objects that had the id `3`. If you still want to be able to access the `id`, remove the `delete i.id` line.

Comment: ah Marty what about the length of the result?